# Unable to clear data in service

Tags: angularjs

I have created a client side cart in my application, i have a controller that handles functions of the cart and a service that is injected into that controller.

On page load i fetch the contents of the cart from **localStorage** and store/prepare it for use:

**CartService.js**

```
var CartService = {};
var newCart = {
    info: {},
    tickets: [],
    customer: {},
    extras: []
};

// Load Cart Data
CartService.load = function() {
    CartService.cart = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('cart')) || newCart;
}

var init = function() {
    CartService.load();
}

init();

return CartService;
```

Now on my cart i have a button that allows the user to **clear all data** from the cart:

```
<a class="pull-left" ng-click="clearCart()" alt="clear" title="Clear Cart?">
  <span class="badge btn-default" style="font-weight:500 !important;color: #666 !important;">
    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span> Clear
  </span>
</a>
```

This is the function that handles that in my controller:

```
$scope.clearCart = function() {

    if (confirm('Are you sure?'))
    {
        $scope.cart = newCart;
        // Clearing The Carts
        CartService.clear();

        // Redirect Page
        $state.go('website.tickets.events.categories');

    }

};
```

Now this is the issue i am having; when the page loads for the **first time**, this works, the cart is cleared both in **CartService.cart** and in the **localStorage**, however any attempts after that to clear the cart fail, it gets cleared alright from localStorage but for some reason i am **unable to clear CartService.cart**.  I know this because when i run **console.log(CartService.cart)** i always see data in it.

However if i refreshed the page and try clicking the button again it works this time, i am confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe $window.localStorage is not currently using the "real" localStorage you could use this service https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage its a lot better than use it directly

Comment: Maybe? Well what i did say was every time i cleared the cart and checked the localStorage the cart was no more there but for some reason CartService.cart retains it's data even after i have set it to undefined.